# Como puedo hacer que un número en Visual Basic deje de ser utilizado en una lista

Tags: visual-studio, vba, vbscript, vbs

Voy a empezar con un poco de contexto. He decidido usar Visual Basic para hacer una tarea bastante común. Necesito que el Visual Basic haga las siguientes cosas.

1. Mire dentro de la carpeta Música y me elimine su contenido
2. Escoja un número aleatorio entre 1 y 5
3. Copie la carpeta con ese número en la carpeta música

Hasta aquí todo fue simple. Pero el problema es que deseo que haga dos cosas más

4. Elimine el número de la selección (Es decir, si sale un 4, los números escogidos serian 1,2,3,5)
5. Cuando no quede más números por escoger, que reinicie por completo.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a hacer eso?
Abajo dejo el código usado.

```
resp.DeleteFolder "F:\Musica\*.*"

Randomize Timer
numero = (1+Int(Rnd()*11))
MsgBox ("El numero que ha salido es" &numero)
Select Case numero
Case 1
    resp.CopyFolder "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Musica\Carpeta 1", "F:\Musica"
Case 2
    resp.CopyFolder "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Musica\Carpeta 2", "F:\Musica"
Case 3
    resp.CopyFolder "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Musica\Carpeta 3", "F:\Musica"
Case 4
    resp.CopyFolder "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Musica\Carpeta 4", "F:\Musica"
Case 5
    resp.CopyFolder "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\Musica\Carpeta 5", "F:\Musica"
End Select
```

Comment: y donde estas guardando los numeros usados?

Comment: Miercoles, tienes razon. No se me había ocurrido.

Comment: y esto, que visual basic es?

Comment: y porque usas un case en lugar de concatenar el numero a la carpeta?

Comment: Pense que el case sería más simple.